# Can I do a jQuery tree traversal with own match/selector function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-traversal

I want to use `$(element).closest(func)` with my own selector/match function. I want to test the elements myself, as existing CSS selectors and jQuery extensions are not enough.

I really hoped that jQuery can at least walk the tree for me, but I can’t find a way...

(I already regret mentioning it, but: I’m searching for a specific custom property on an element object, and no, it is not a HTML attribute, so there is no selector for it...)

Comment: You can use `$(element).parents().filter((index, el)=>yourMatcher())` - and use `index` to determine which is the closest.

Comment: @freedomn-m I want to keep the “quit on first match” characteristics of “closest()”.

Comment: Take the polyfill from here and and your own match function.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest  this essentially does `el = el.parentElement` until a match is found, so will give you your stop on first match